# How to check after each entry in Sudoku that it is valid or not

Tags: android, algorithm, sudoku, error-checking

I was searching for a Sudoku app on google play-store and I found [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brainium.sudoku.free&hl=en) app very interesting. They have various difficulty levels. What I find in this app is they have a hint button and auto error check which will automatically detach whether your entered number is correct or not. Now I want to know how can I create a algorithm which will do the same job about entered number is correct or not. Also how there hint button works?

**Edit after Paul's comment:** Now I know how to check if the entered value is correct or not. Now the remaining issue is how to provide hint similar to the hints provided by the above mentioned app.
[image: When I tab hint button][image: When I press next][image]

**PS:** let me know if this question is not constructive for the site. I will happily delete this question because I am not sure about should I put this question here or other stackoverflow community.

Comment: Is there a problem just having the program solve the puzzle before the game starts, storing the solution in an array, then checking if the entered value matches?

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds confusing. On the one hand you ask how to verify that sudoku position is valid or not, but in the example you show how a program assists with finding a position where to put a number (not checking your sudoku, but making a move to solve one).

To check sudoku you only need to verify that the numbers in each row/column/square are valid. This is easily achieved with a set data structure. I do not know android and do not have time to look, so here is a simple python code which takes an array of strings and tells whether the sudoku is valid:

```
from collections import Counter

def isValidCounter(cnt):
    del cnt[0]
    for i in cnt:
        if cnt[i] > 1:
            return False
    return True

def isValid(arr):
    M = [[int(i) if i != '.' else 0 for i in line] for line in arr]

    # rows
    for i in M:
        if not isValidCounter(Counter(i)):
            return False

    # columns
    for i in xrange(9):
        if not isValidCounter(Counter(M[j][i] for j in xrange(9))):
            return False

    # squares
    squares = [
        [M[0][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)] + [M[1][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)] + [M[2][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)],
        [M[0][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)] + [M[1][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)] + [M[2][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)],
        [M[0][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)] + [M[1][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)] + [M[2][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)],

        [M[3][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)] + [M[4][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)] + [M[5][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)],
        [M[3][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)] + [M[4][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)] + [M[5][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)],
        [M[3][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)] + [M[4][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)] + [M[5][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)],

        [M[6][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)] + [M[7][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)] + [M[8][i] for i in xrange(0, 3)],
        [M[6][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)] + [M[7][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)] + [M[8][i] for i in xrange(3, 6)],
        [M[6][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)] + [M[7][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)] + [M[8][i] for i in xrange(6, 9)]
    ]
    for square in squares:
        if not isValidCounter(Counter(square)):
            return False

    return True
```

And here is how this array looks like:

```
[
  "53..7....",
  "6..195...",
  ".98....6.",
  "8...6...3",
  "4..8.3..1",
  "7...2...6",
  ".6....28.", 
  "...419..5",
  "....8..79"
]
```